# Getting the hash key whose value array contains a given string

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following code:

```
country_code = infer_country # will grab a user's two character country code
region = 'us' # united states by default
region_map = {
      "au" => ["au"], # australia
      "al" => ["al", "ba", "bg", "hr", "md", "me", "mk", "ro", "si"], # bulgaria and the balkans
      "cn" => ["cn"], # china
      "ee" => ["ee", "lt", "lv"], # estonia and the baltics
      "fi" => ["fi"], # finland
      "at" => ["at", "ch", "de"], # germany, austria, switzerland
      "cy" => ["cy", "gr", "mt"], # greece, cyprus, malta
      "hk" => ["hk"], # hong_kong
      "id" => ["id"], # indonesia
      "it" => ["it"], # italy
      "jp" => ["jp"], # japan
      "kp" => ["kp", "kr"], # korea
      "ar" => ["ar", "bl", "bo", "br", "bz", "cl", "co", "cr", "cu", "do", "ec", "gf", "gp", "gt", "hn", 
               "ht", "mf", "mq", "mx", "ni", "pa", "pe", "pr", "py", "sv", "uy", "ve"], # latin america including brazil
      "my" => ["my"], # malaysia
      "af" => ["af", "eg", "iq", "ir", "sa", "ye", "sy", "il", "jo", "ps", "lb", "om", "kw", "qa", "bh"], # middle east
      "nl" => ["nl"], # netherlands
      "no" => ["no"], # norway
      "pl" => ["pl"], # poland
      "pt" => ["pt"], # portugal
      "ph" => ["ph"], # philippines
      "ru" => ["ru"], # russia
      "rs" => ["rs"], # serbia
      "sg" => ["sg"], # singapore
      "za" => ["za"], # south africa
      "bn" => ["bn", "bu", "kh", "la", "tl", "vn"], # south east asia
      "es" => ["es"], # spain
      "tw" => ["tw"], # taiwan
      "th" => ["th"], # thailand
      "tr" => ["tr"], # turkey
      "gb" => ["gb" ] # united kingdom
    }.invert
 # version 0.0
 region_map.each do |key, value|
   if key.include? country_code
     region = value
     break
   end
 end

 puts region
```

If `country_code` is `"gb"`, then `"gb"` should be printed out. If `country_code` is in south east asia, say it's `"vn"`, then `"bn"` should be printed out.

How can I elegantly solve this problem? I can restructure my hash if necessary.

Comment: Build a reverse hash. Then lookup is as trivial as it can be.

Comment: And please use `%w(at ch de)` instead of `["at", "ch", "de"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def find_region(country_code)
  pair = @region_map.find{|k, v| v.include?(country_code)}
  pair && pair.first
end

find_region('gb') # => "gb"
find_region('bz') # => "ar"
find_region('lv') # => "ee"
find_region('ls') # => nil
```

Comment: nice, and if i wanted it to return "us" by default? (also, updated my answer with version 0.0, but converting to your version as it is much better). alright i think i have it, thanks!

Comment: You can provide a default value if you use the `Hash.new` constructor pattern: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new

Answer (score 2):

```
def find_region(country_code)
  @region_map.each {|k,v| return k if v.include? country_code}
  nil
end
```

Comment: change "nil" to "us" and i think this is the best answer, nice!

Comment: fc: Better, methinks, to have def find_region(country_code='us') and include 'us' in the list.  It makes no sense to have find_region('sl') return 'us'. ('sl' -> 'Shangra-La')

Answer (score 0):

```
region_map = Hash.new("us").merge(
  "au" => "au",
  "al" => "al",
  "ba" => "al",
  "bg" => "al",
  "hr" => "al",
  "md" => "al",
  "me" => "al",
  "mk" => "al",
  "ro" => "al",
  "si" => "al",
  "al" => "al", 
  "cn" => "cn",
  ...
)

region_map["non existing code"] # => "us"
region_map[nil] # => "us"
region_map["au"] # => "au"
region_map["ba"] # => "al"
region_map["cn"] # => "cn"
```

or

```
def region_map code
  case code
  when "au"
    "au"
  when "al", "ba", "bg", "hr", "md", "me", "mk", "ro", "si"
    "al"
  when "cn"
    "cn"
  when "ee", "lt", "lv"
    "ee"
  ...
  else
    "us"
  end
end

region_map("non existing code") # => "us"
region_map(nil) # => "us"
region_map("au") # => "au"
region_map("ba") # => "al"
region_map("cn") # => "cn"
```